# Python web request slow through Proxy

Tags: python, windows, proxy, python-requests, urllib

Some background: I work for a corporation which uses a proxy. Ping/nslookup are blocked, and I think this may be contributing to the following problem. The operating system being used is Windows, and the version of Python I'm testing 3.4.3.

I'm trying to create an application that communicates with a webservice, and this application will run inside our network. However, all requests take over 10 seconds to complete, while in the web browser it loads in under a second. Note that these requests *succeed*, they just take too long to be usable.

I profiled the application using the cProfile module, and I found that the application is spending 11 seconds on *gethostbyaddr*, and 4 seconds on *gethostbyname*.

I'm not familiar enough with networks, but is this a timeout? Why does the request go through despite the timeout? How do I disable these operations? And if I can't, is there a library that does not use these operations?

I tried both the requests and urllib modules. Pip is also exceedingly slow and may be because of the same cause.

Thanks in advance for any help or information on this subject.

### Edit

I just tried monkey patching socket.gethostbyaddr and socket.gethostbyname, and the speed delay was gone. This doesn't feel like a proper solution though.

```
import requests
import socket

def do_nothing(*args):
    return None
socket.gethostbyaddr = do_nothing
socket.gethostbyname = do_nothing

r = requests.get('https://google.com')
print(r.status_code) # prints 200
```

Comment: These functions are doing DNS lookup. Your browser likely caches DNS responses, which is why it's fast.

Comment: Not sure if that's the case, Ruby worked instantly (had to disable SSL verification because of errors on Windows), and Java. But I'll need to test some more tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: Try passing headers / cookies / certs to mimic your browser. Perhaps your proxy is suspicious of programmatic browsing?

Comment: Programmatic browsing through anything except Python isn't so slow, so that's not it. I also just monkey patched socket.gethostbyaddr and socket.gethostbyname to return None, and the delay is gone. But I'd rather not have to resort to that if possible.